# lapply from 1:n for each element of a list R

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization, apply, lapply

I'm trying to write a function that will add a list element to another list if that list element is less than any previous value in the list. I have a non-vectorized version that works:

```
myList <- c(14, 35, 12, 54, 67, 8, 32, 3, 78)

minVec <- function(x){
# Return a list of all numbers from x which are less than any previous number in the list
  outList <- list(x[1])
  for(i in 2:length(x)){
    if(x[i] < min(x[1:i - 1])){
      outList <- c(outList, x[i])}
  }
  return(unlist(outList))
}

minVec(myList)
```

But I need to do this many times over many lists and I want to use lapply to speed it up. The problem is that for each element `n` of list `x` I need to be able to find the min of the subset `x[1:n - 1]`. Can this be done in lapply (or otherwise vectorized)? How do I say "for each element of this list add the element to a new list if the element is less than any previous value in the list"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
unique(cummin(myList))
```

#### EDIT some explanation:

the **min of the subset x[1:n - 1] for each n of list** is the **cumulative  minima** of
the list. Since `cummin` is vectorized , the result have the same size of the input list, so we need `unique` to remove deplicated.

The same solution can be generalized for :

- cumulative maxima : `cummax`
- cumulative sum : `cumsum`
- cumulative product : `cumprod`

Comment: Boy, that really cuts down on wasted time!

Comment: That's really slick, thanks. Is there a more general solution if I need to apply a function other than min, max, sum, etc?

Comment: This is interesting but I'd ask you if you may add, if possible, any supplementary info to your approach.

Comment: It's just three parts,  `myList`, `cummin(myList)`, and `unique(cummin(myList))`

Comment: @TomR you can plug in an arbitrary function instead of `min` into: `sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) min(x[1:i]))`, but it will be a *lot* slower

Comment: Way to find the perfect function. I'm sure it's the best one in this case, but if you wanted to do that with other functions as well, a vectorized alternative is `unique(Reduce(function(x,y) min(x,y), myList, accumulate=T))`